# Which NSURLConnection wrapper handles GET and POST equally well?

Tags: objective-c, http-post, nsurlconnection

Which NSURLConnection wrapper handles GET and POST equally well ?

**For GET method**, I prefer google's **GTMHTTPFetcher** over **ASIHTTPRequest**. ASIHTTPRequest uses delegate, which probably the idea you will come up with normally. But that's the exactly reason I chose not to use it because when you have several connections(many connections in my case), then each connection has its own delegate and you end up with too many object. Or you can have just 1 delegate but you have find a way to find out which response is for which connection.

GTMHTTPFetcher handle this way much better in my opinion. It uses 1 SEL for 1 connection, sorta like target-action model. The code is much cleaner than delegate model.

**But for POST method**,  ASIHTTPRequest has **ASIFormDataRequest**. I did not find an easy way to do POST with GTMHTTPFetcher. It does have **setPostData** method to set post data. But you have to set post body and those mime parameters by yourselves(from what I have see) And that's the headache. I find it has another class called **GTMHTTPUploadFetcher**. But I can't really figure out how to use it (I keep getting the NSAssert "need upload location hdr").

So for POST,  I guess ASIHTTPRequest is easier.

I did not get a chance to use [facebook-ios-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/src/FBRequest.h). And would like to hear other opinion about it.

So is there NSURLConnection wrapper handle both GET and POST well ? And any idea how to use GTMHTTPUploadFetcher?

Comment: `ASIHTTPRequest` can also use blocks instead of delegates, which can be used to specify different selectors per request.

Answer (score 0):

The [GTMMIMEDocument](http://code.google.com/p/gtm-http-fetcher/source/browse/trunk/Source/GTMMIMEDocument.h) class is used to create a stream for uploading via GTMHTTPFetcher (or via anything else that takes an NSInputStream.)  An example is [here](http://code.google.com/p/gtm-http-fetcher/wiki/MultipartPost).

GTMMIMEDocument keeps a sparse list of the data parts to be uploaded, avoiding duplicating the data in memory.